# NameError: global name 'valid_month" is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, web-deployment, web-development-server

I'm doing Udacity's Web Development Course and I'm having a problem in lesson 2 # 35. Here is my code.

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
    What is your birthdate?
    <br>
    <label> Month
        <input type="text" name="month">
    </label>
    <label> Day
        <input type="text" name="day">
    </label>
    <label> Year
        <input type="text" name="year">
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
          'August','September','October','November','December']
    months_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)


    def valid_month(month):
        if month:
            short_month = month[:3].lower()
            if short_month in months:
                return months_abbvs.get(short_month)

    def valid_day(day):
        if day and day.isdigit():
            day = int(day)
            if day > 0 and day <= 31:
                return day

    def valid_year(year):
        if year and year.isdigit():
            year = int(year)
            if year >= 1900 and year <= 2020:
                return year

    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form)

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not (user_month and user_day and user_day):
            self.response.out.write(form)
        else:
            self.response.write("Thanks! That's a totally calid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I'm running it through google app engine. When I click submit on the form in the browser I get:

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

When I look at the cmd prompt from where I'm running the server I get the error:

```
INFO     2017-11-01 22:09:22,153 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 
200 382
ERROR    2017-11-02 02:09:46,470 webapp2.py:1528] global name 
'valid_month' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in 
__call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in 
__call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in 
default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in 
__call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in 
dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in 
dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\python-docs-
samples\appengine\standard\hello_world\main.py", line 50, in post
user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
NameError: global name 'valid_month' is not defined
ERROR    2017-11-02 02:09:46,470 wsgi.py:279]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 
267, in Handle
INFO     2017-11-01 22:09:46,477 module.py:821] default: "POST / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 -
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in 
__call__
response = self._internal_error(e)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in 
__call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in 
__call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in 
default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in 
__call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in 
dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-
sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in 
dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mmelv\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\python-docs-
samples\appengine\standard\hello_world\main.py", line 50, in post
user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
NameError: global name 'valid_month' is not defined
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is in the
    user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month))
line, but I've tried changing indentation from spaces to tabs and back to spaces, rewriting the whole code, and restarting the server, all to no avail. Someone help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling member functions from within the class to which they belong, you need to preface them with `self.`. Additionally, all of your member functions, like `valid_month()`, `valid_day()`, and `valid_year()` must have `self` as the first value of their actual parameters. Furthermore, any references to static class variables such as `months` and `months_abbvs` must also be prefaced with `self.`.

Additionally, there may be a logic error in the return values of `valid_month()`, `valid_day()`, and `valid_year()`. Each is returning a string, yet the conditional in `post()` is evaluating whether or not all three are `True`. Also, the conditional in `valid_months()` is probably meant to check if `short_month` is in `months_abbvs` as opposed to in `months`.

Try replacing the current `post()` function with the following:

```
def post(self):

    user_month = self.valid_month(self.request.get("month"))
    user_day   = self.valid_day(self.request.get("day"))
    user_year  = self.valid_year(self.request.get("year"))

    if not(user_month and user_day and user_day):

        self.response.out.write(form)

    else:

        self.response.write("Thanks! That's a totally calid day!")
```

Then change the following function headers:

For `valid_month()`, replace the existing function with the following:

```
def valid_month(self, month):

    if month:

        short_month = month[:3].lower()

        if short_month in self.months_abbvs:

            return True
```

For `valid_day()`, replace the existing function with the following:

```
def valid_day(self, day):

    if day and day.isdigit():

        day = int(day)

        if day > 0 and day <= 31:

            return True
```

For `valid_year()`, replace the existing function with the following:

```
def valid_year(self, year):

    if year and year.isdigit():

        year = int(year)

        if year >= 1900 and year <= 2020:

            return True
```

Comment: TypeError: valid_month() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: I got it to work by moving the functions valid_month etc inside of the post function. But not the page just reloads the form regardless of if the input is valid

Comment: @MMelvin0581 That's not necessarily a great approach because it will redefine those nested functions every time `post()` is called. You definitely want to take advantage of the `self` keyword for member functions so that they are only defined once.

Comment: @MMelvin0581 `self.request.get()` must be returning two values. Try adding `print(self.request.get("month")` to the line before the assignment to `user_month`. What does that print out?

Comment: line 31, in valid_month
        if short_month in months:
    NameError: global name 'months' is not defined

Comment: @MMelvin0581 See the last edit You just needed `self` before `months` and `months_abbvs` for this one.

Comment: Awesome! it's going trough now, but it is reloading the form regardless of if the input is valid

Comment: @MMelvin0581 That's probably a logic error with your decisional in `post()` versus the return values from `valid_month()`, `valid_day()` and `valid_year()` from what I can see. Let me make another edit.

Comment: same, it's still just reloading the form

Comment: @MMelvin0581 I caught a glitch causing `valid_month()` to return `False` for every month but May: Change `if short_month in self.months:` to `if short_month in self.months_abbvs:`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MMelvin0581 No problem! Glad I could help you get it worked out!